# jQuery issue with Chrome vs. IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

```
function runComplete() {
    var $elem=$(document.getElementById('quiz_section'));
    var center="<br /><h1>Your Score:</h1><h2>"+document.getElementById('quiz_score').innerHTML+"</h2><br /><br /><br /><a href='javascript:location.reload(true)'><h5>Try Again?</h5></a>";
    $elem.html('<form id="comp" style="width:33.333333%;height:1px;background-color:lightblue;border=1px solid #000000;pading:10px">'+center+'</form>');
    var theight=$elem.height()+20;
    $elem.css('height','1px');
    $elem.animate({height:theight});
}
```

In IE, the code above runs great!  In Chrome... eh... not so much.

It is supposed to animate the form and make it "fall down", instead, it doesn't resize it.  I use a very similar technique (same animation) in other spots of my code and it all runs just fine in Chrome, this is the only thing that doesn't animate.  Any ideas?

Here is a demo of the quiz:

http://dalexl.tripod.com/HTMLQUIZ.htm

Comment: You know you can just call `$("#quiz_section")` instead (that won't help solve your specific problem though

Comment: You have a small error in your inline CSS, 'border=' instead of 'border:'

Comment: Oh, thanks :) That will help clean up my code!

Comment: @KARASZI WOW, that was a problem that I was dealing with a TON.  IE was displaying a border but Chrome wasn't THANKS :)

Comment: There, I added a link to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `$elem.hide().slideDown()` instead.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for changing it?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with your current code; it's rather messy.  However, this should work.  Please show a demo.

Comment: Could you at least explain why I should use this rather than my stated method :o

Comment: It's simpler, and it will also animate border and padding.

Comment: Works great in IE, not so much in Google Chrome... it did fix my issue with having to add the padding values :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment and it came out that was the problem I post it here :)

A bad inline style was included with `border=` instead of `border:`

Btw. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u4w36/1/) to play with it.